# How do I style a inc via html object with css?

Tags: css, html, object, include

I was searching for a way to use includes without server side assistance and found the object .inc method here.

Example: `<object name="foo" type="text/html" data="foo.inc"/></object>`

Which works great, except I can't style anything inside the .inc file without linking the style sheet within it.

Is there a way to do with the parent html file? like: `object:foo #innerelement {}`
That is my thinking anyways, like there should be some sort of notation for this.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the answer is **no** because this method is implemented similar to how an `iframe` tag would work.